# my two screens don't work

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I am a windows user who wants to try the linux ecosystem starting to use ubuntu but this gave me a big problem. Since I started the live two of my screens one fails (vga) and stays off but the operating system thinks it's on and working. I already tried changing xorg to wayland, trying to install the video drivers (it's an amd r9 380) and nothing. Once I enter recovery mode and since that mode places a very simple driver, apparently the two screens work but the image is cloned but I think that using the integrated kernel driver for amd fails fatally. I even ventured to download very old versions of ubuntu like Ubuntu 17.10 (I checked and the kernel is 4.13.0 generic) then I tried Ubuntu 18.4 and the two screens no longer work, of course and it doesn't work in the latest version of ubuntu. What could I try to do to solve this problem?
Note: my graph gives video to an HDMI and a VGA monitor but with a DVI to VGA converter. And this fails both in live mode and normally installed

**Solution**: (not 100% for sure) is to modify the kernel by adding "amdgpu.dc=0" and that's it, my two screens work. The problem is that my GPU has HDMI, DisplayPort, DVI-D, DVI-I output and the problem is the DVI-I port which the operating system detects as DVI-D-1 and the DVI-D protocol does not support analog signal That's why it doesn't turn on but the OS detects it. With the solution disabling DC (Display Core) it seems to fix everything but I think that disabling this function can cause even more problems. I'm not a very advanced user so the problems it can cause with DC disabled I don't know

Comment: Very old version (17.10) was not a good idea; rather, did you try with latest LTS version? (22.04.2 LTS)

Comment: Of course, I installed the newest version and it didn't work for me, try trying old versions and if it works, I tried up to 17.10 and both screens worked but when I jump to 18.4 it stops working until the latest version (22.04.2 LTS which also tried). I think it may be the kernel's fault due to a driver. I also tried other linux distributions such as manjaro, pop os, linux mint, fedora. Same problem

Comment: Start by watching your booting system discover its hardware with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. That will let you know which program handles the displays. Investigate that program.

Comment: Replying to Waltinator. run the code and dump it into a text file, I put it in pastebin all that it throws. Link https://pastebin.com/7S74kTqP